# Queue Linked List for Python

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, stack

so my teacher is having us implement a queue using a stack linked list for my data structures class. I have come up with the following code, and I seem to not understand the error that python gives me when i run my unit test ...

Here is my code `

```
class QueueLinked:

    def __init__(self,capacity):
        self.capacity = capacity # a capacity
        self.num_items = 0
        self.front = None
        self.rear = None

    def is_empty(self):     # This function will retrun a bool if the number of items is = to 0
        return self.num_items == 0

    def is_full(self):
        return self.num_items == self.capacity

    def enqueue(self, item):
        if self.num_items == self.capacity:
            raise IndexError('Can\'t  enqueue into full queue.')
        else:
            self.num_items +=1
            temp = Node()  # this creates a temporary node
            oldrear = self.rear
            self.rear =   temp
            oldrear.set_next(self.rear)


    def dequeue(self):
        if self.num_items == 0:  # this will through an exception because if there are no items we cant pop
            raise IndexError('Can\'t dequeue from empty queue.')
        else:
            self.num_items -=1
            oldfront = self.front
            self.front = self.front.get_next()
            return oldfront.get_data()


    def num_in_queue(self):
        return self.num_items


class Node:

    def __init__(self):
        self.next = None  # this initializes a node with next pointing to none

    def set_data(self, data):  # this passes the parameter data to the data portion of the node
        self.data = data  # this constructs that data portion of a node everytime we create a node

    def get_data(self):  # get data from the node that was previous newwest
        return self.data  # returns the data from that node

    def set_next(self, newNext):  # this will set a new next to point as in after the head
        self.next = newNext  # this constructs the next portion of the 2 part portion from the node

    def get_next(self):  # this will retrieve the next value from the node
        return self.next`
```

Here is my Unit test case

```
import unittest

from queues import *


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):


    # testing an empty Array

    def test_if_empty(self):  # we will test if the array is empty using is_empty
        q = QueueLinked(3)  # [none,none,none]
        self.assertTrue(q.is_empty())  # Should be True

    def test_if_full(self):
        q = QueueLinked(3)
        q.enqueue(4)
        q.enqueue(5)
        q.enqueue(8)
        self.assertTrue(q.is_empty())

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
```

and this is the error that i keep on receiving my Pycharm ..

```
    Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
Launching unittests with arguments python -m unittest test_queues.TestCase in C:\Users\M\Documents\CSC 202\Labs\Lab3
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "C:\Users\M\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 605, in run
    testMethod()
  File "C:\Users\M\Documents\CSC 202\Labs\Lab3\test_queues.py", line 17, in test_if_full
    q.enqueue(4)
  File "C:\Users\M\Documents\CSC 202\Labs\Lab3\queues.py", line 63, in enqueue
    oldrear.set_data(self.rear)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_data'
```

What am I not understand ?

Comment: the first pass `self.rear == None` so when you set `oldrear` you are trying to call `None.set_data`

Comment: Did you include the correct code? I don't see `oldrear.set_data()` in `Queue().enqueue()`

Answer (score 0):

As someone in the comments already pointed out, the traceback you posted says that `set_data` is called in the `enqueue` method, which is not reflected by your code which only calls `set_next`. However I'm assuming that you get a similar error with `set_next`.

In `QueueLinked` you initialize `self.rear` with the value `None`. In the `enqueue` method you initialize the variable `oldrear` with the value of `self.rear` which by the time `enqueue` is called is still `None`. At this point both `oldrear` and `self.rear` are `None`. You than try to call `set_next` on `oldrear` (which still == `None`) and get an error telling you that `None` doens't have a `set_next` method.

I haven't gone over the entire code, so I'm not sure if this is correct, but I assume you could just initialize `self.rear = Node()` and it would work.